# "Could not find triehash executable" error

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-18.04, apt

I was trying to build the [apt repository](https://github.com/Debian/apt), but ran into the following error when running `cmake ..`:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 (message):
  Could not find triehash executable
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cmake tries to find `triehash` utility in your system. Is it installed? If no use `sudo apt install triehash`

Comment: Doesn't work, gives the error - `E: Unable to locate package triehash`.

Comment: Ok. Then you can try to build it manually from [repo](https://github.com/julian-klode/triehash)

Comment: It seems to be a single perl file, with no way to build it. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You need to put `triehash.pl` file somewhere in your `PATH` without `pl` extention and make it executable. Something like this: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julian-klode/triehash/master/triehash.pl -O triehash && chmod a+x triehash && sudo mv triehash /usr/bin`